# Application stops unexpectedly on playing wav file from res/raw folder

Tags: android

I have a "comin.wav" in my res/raw folder. But when I try to play the file like this , the application stops unexpectedly. There is no error displayed in the code. The error only comes when the code runs on the emulator

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this,R.raw.comin);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

What should I do??

Comment: please post your logcat.

Comment: It says something like "PLAYER_SET_DATA_SOURCE complete with an error or info PVMF" then it says error not supported

Comment: Supposedly, the error is in .prepare () .

Comment: Got it rectified. Some android platforms have a bug playing wav files in this manner. COnverting it to mp3 format did the job !! :)